# Why are the chapters in The Bastard of Istanbul named after ingredients of ashure?

Tags: symbolism, elif-shafak, the-bastard-of-istanbul

*The Bastard of Istanbul* is a novel by Elif Şafak which explores Turkish and Armenian culture and history; you can [read a summary and 9-page excerpt online](https://www.bookbrowse.com/excerpts/index.cfm/book_number/1944/the-bastard-of-istanbul). One of the questions from the "reading guide" at the above link intrigued me:

> What is the significance of naming each chapter after an ingredient of the dessert ashure?

[Aşure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashure) is a dessert eaten in both Turkey and Armenia (in the latter it is called anuşabur). It appears to have a lot of cultural significance, and it's mentioned explicitly both in *The Bastard of Istanbul* and in another of Şafak's novels. So I think this question is very interesting and worth exploring. **Why are the chapters named after aşure ingredients, and does this tie into the themes of the story?**